# Matching a query using VLookup from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a sheet here called `July 5 2016`. It looks like this

```
Pers.No   Employee/app.name   Date ... etc ... etc  .. Rec.Order
12345      Bob Jones           Jan 2016                EXVM_SI15H55
etc          etc                 etc                     etc
```

I have another file called `Sheet1` which looks like

```
Description            PEATS  Rec.Order
Helped moving things   284367 EXVM_SI15H55
Database dev           232367 BXVM_SI15H55
 etc                    etc     etc
```

What I want to do is create another column in `July 5 2016` Called `Description` and `PEATS`. I want to use `VLOOKUP` or something similar to take the Rec.Order that is already in the first sheet, and search that Rec.Order in `Sheet1`, and populate the corresponding `PEATS` number and `Description`

How should I go about this?
Thanks

Comment: If you use VLOOKUP `Rec.Order` must be to the left of the other two on sheet1.  Otherwise you will want an INDEX/MATCH formula.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

On Worksheet("July 5 2016") you can't use a `Vlookup` because the information you want is to the *left* of your index value. Instead use an index/match formula.

For description:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,MATCH($D1,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100,0))
```

For PEATS:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH($D1,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100,0))
```

You see, you are matching your lookup value to the corresponding column on Sheet1, which in turn gives you the row it is found on, which selects the data from either column A or B to give you what you want.

Comment: Just a note for @Cresjoy - `Index/Match` can be quite powerful, compared to `Vlookup()`.  [Here's one page](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) showing how to use `Index/Match`, but starting with comparing it to `Vlookup`.  I learned `Index/Match` and never looked back!

Answer (score 0):

Well then, let's save `VLOOKUP()`'s reputation!

Of course `INDEX/MATCH` works nicely here, and once you understand how it works, it's the simple approach. Today (2021), we have `XLOOKUP()` with some helpful features in addition to doing what `INDEX/MATCH` does but in a straightforward way rather than the slightly involved way `INDEX/MATCH` does. Either is a very nice solution to this problem, then and now.

However, `VLOOKUP()` is being falsely libeled here. It cannot "look left" ON ITS OWN, but then neither can `INDEX()` or `MATCH()` do it on their own either. However, with a small trick, using `INDEX()`, it can look anywhere AND do it with two columns no matter how many columns the table has. You can always  In other words, with the help of a very simple `INDEX()`, it does precisely what `INDEX()` does with the help of `MATCH()`. (I stress that since I often hear from people using a two function combo to do something neither of the functions can do on their own, that somehow using `VLOOKUP()` in a... wait for it... two function combo... is somehow not a solution fit for humans. Ugh...)

So how?

Well, the problem is the table parameter in `VLOOKUP()`. The lookup column has to be to the left of the desired information's column. No problem with the first parameter or the last: The first one since you know exactly where or what your lookup value is and the last one because you surely know whether you need FALSE (probably) or TRUE. The third one is no problem because it is ALWAYS "2".

So, the table. You have some range of data in mind. You just need to rearrange it. Probably you can't just move columns as either it's not your data to screw with the structure of, or that would mess up other work, or you just don't want to. But... `INDEX()` can do it for you. In fact, not only can it rearrange the columns for the lookup, it cuts down the columns used in the function from however many there are in the source data to just two in the lookup. The same thing `INDEX/MATCH` is supposed to be so valuable for.

`INDEX()` takes three parameters in most uses. Using the fourth parameter can be useful for several things, not least of which is putting physically separate ranges of cells together in a single column. But consider the usual three:  The first one is the source data, some range/Named Range/formal Table/whatever (even a construct from other functions that you want evaluated, but do not want to exist "in real life"). Easy Peasey. It's the second and third ones that make it interesting.

Third one first as this is where the magic occurs. The "Column/s" parameter. You can specify the column/s to use in many ways, but the one most don't know of, or think of if they do, is using an `Array Constant`. Those looks like this:  {3,2,8,6,7,8}. You put column numbers in the `{}` and `INDEX()` uses those columns. You can leave some out (Like it seems I did: 1, 4, and 5 would seem to be missing, eh? And any higher than 8.), you can put some "out of order" (Like it seems I did with "3, 2".), and you can even have a given column appear more than once (Like it seems I did with column 8 appearing twice).

So for the column parameter (row if you are doing the rare horizontal lookup) you use two numbers in an array constant:  First, the column you want to find the lookup value in, and second, the column you want to find the data in. (See how the column parameter in the lookup is always "2"?) I'll give an example in a moment after addressing the Row parameter.

Any time you use something like an array constant in `INDEX()` the frequent shortcut for the other parameter, either one, of leaving it blank, or using a "0" for it, fails. So you have to specify an actual value for the row parameter. There are two obvious ways, one used for decades and still great, the other using the newer function `SEQUENCE()`. The first is dead simple, the second is just as simple, but can become (interestingly) complicated if you wish.

The first is just `=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS("source table")))` That's if you want it to grow and shrink with the data table. If you don't care, just do `ROW(1:20000)` (change to whatever the high number needs to be). The second, using `SEQUENCE()` would be `SEQUENCE(ROWS("source table"))` or just a number if you you aren't worrying about growing and shrinking.

So, here's a full version of what I'm talking about:

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,INDEX(A1:F20000,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:F20000))),{4,2}),2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,INDEX(A1:F20000,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:F20000)),{4,2}),2,FALSE)
```

The source range being A1:F20000, the lookup value entered in G1, the column you want to look it up in being 4, and the column you want a result from being 2.

`INDEX()` takes the source table, and returns all its rows, but only columns 4 and 2, in that order (4, then 2), to the `VLOOKUP()` function. `VLOOKUP()` looks in the first column `INDEX()` presents it (4) for the value in G1 and when it finds it, looks in the corresponding row of the second column `INDEX()` presents it (2) to find what to return.

So yeah, of course `INDEX/MATCH` (and nowadays `XLOOKUP()` though that is NOT always a pure, simple replacement for `INDEX/MATCH`) is better. Once understood (and it's not THAT hard to understand, though usually websites don't explain it well, just jabber about how it comes together), it is SIMPLE and pretty direct.

But to say `VLOOKUP()` "can't look left"??? NO. Just wrong and mean. It's almost a religion to dis (or for people who still say "program" not "app"... "crap on") `VLOOKUP()` but my old friend is very helpful and much more nuanced in what its parameters can do than almost anyone give it credit for.

(It will never give a reference as a result though, it seems. Or at least, I can't yet find a way to force it to. So `INDEX()` wins there as that can be VERY useful. Less so nowadays, but still...)